# Proper IIS uninstall and re-installation of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-7, iis, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking to do a full reinstall of Visual Studio 2012, and every time I try to start up the installer it goes to the splash screen and immediately closes, without displaying any sort of dialogue. I've had this problem before, and the solution was to do a complete removal of IIS and then repeat installation, but that doesn't seem to be working. I followed the attached guide to do the removal, and for good measure went in and uninstalled anything that had to do with PHP, MySQL, or Visual Studio 2012.

Still no success, even after all that. Best I can figure, I still haven't completely removed IIS, but I don't see any indication it's running.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1169703.aspx/1

Comment: ask in the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup. They will request some logs and give you the steps to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did, in fact, finally find a resolution to this. I originally was going to do a reinstall of windows to get Visual Studio to install, but instead used a pendrive to try just upgrading and repairing to see if that would fix my problem. It did.